# Multilanguage asp.net site with aspx in different levels

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, vs-web-site-project

I've been working in a multilanguage site build with asp.net and visual c#.
I'm using Local_resources to get my aspx files in Spanish and english. 
If a use my aspx in the root of the website the Local_resources folder find the aproppiate resx for my aspx (because both have the same name). But if i put all my aspx into a folder created in the root directory, everything stop working:

[image]

as you can see i have a folder named "Inventario" and inside that folder i have Productos.aspx. 
In App_LocalResources i have two files, one for spanish and one for english.
If i put Productos.aspx in the root directory they work fine, but i need them like in the image and like that is not working.
What should i do to the resx files to point to Inventario/Productos.aspx ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new `App_LocalResources` folder under `Inventario`, then copy `Productos.aspx.*.resx` from `<root>\App_LocalResources` to `Inventario\App_LocalResources`, then rebuild your solution.

Comment: That's an interesting solution! I'm using resources too... We use the App_GlobalResources folder, with different resources files, one resource file name for each application module, and, of course, it works. I wonder, are there any other advantages of putting the module's resources in its own App_LocalResources folder, instead of putting them in the global folder (besides better code organization)?

Comment: Modularity / self-containment, I guess: you have the pages and their related sources under the same folder.

Comment: i followed frédéric steps and it worked perfectly, i'm gonna go with this answer because i think is organized to have everything with its own resources together. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm.. thanks :) I will look into that. Perhaps we'll start organizing our resources like that.